# GoogleAppEngine web proxy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

Does anyone know of a simple open source proxy capable of running on google app engine or where to start in making one? (preferably in python, I'm trying to bypass a site blocking system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Mirrorrr:

http://code.google.com/p/mirrorrr/

Or Masher Nations, Itube Appengine, Tohr, etc.